# Как сохранить данные в базу данных MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Имеется готовая таблица птиц.[image: Таблица]

В `php` файле из этой таблицы я загружаю name в `select` тэг. Это выглядит вот так:

```
<? php
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.cc.puv.fi", "e1500954", "UrSpkWveR2Hb", "e1500954_bird");
$con - > set_charset('utf8'); //Thanks Teemu

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
//fetch content of the bird-table. Be sure to use exactly right table name.
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bird");
echo "<h1>Bird report solution</h1>";
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"observation.php\">";
//browse the result of the query to show it on the web-page. Be sure to use exactly right column names.
echo "Bird: <select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
  echo "<option>";
  echo $row['name'];
  echo "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br>Place: <input type=\"text\">";
echo "<br>Time: <input  type=\"text\">";
echo "<br>Email: <input type=\"text\">";
echo "<br>Place: <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\">";
echo "</form>";
mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Нужно сохранить данные из полей `place, time, email, bird_id` в другую таблицу[image: Таблица 2]

Сделать это я должен через другой `php` файл, который выглядит вот так:

```
<?php
//connect as in previous example
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql.cc.puv.fi","e1500954","UrSpkWveR2Hb","e1500954_bird");
$con->set_charset('utf8'); //Thanks Teemu

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO observation (bird_id, place, time, person_email) values (" . $_POST["bird"] .",'" . $_POST["place"] . "','". $_POST["time"]. "','" . $_POST["email"]. "');");

//disconnect as in previous example
mysqli_close($con);
echo "Observation saved";
?>
```

После того, как я нажимаю кнопку `save` пишет якобы данные сохранены, но в таблицу ничего не добавляется.

Comment: Для наглядности, можете посетить саму страницу. www.cc.puv.fi/~e1500954/bird.php

Comment: Не советую данные бд писать в самом вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что каждый `input` и `select` должны иметь параметр `name`, этот параметр при пост или гет запросе заносится в глобальную переменную `$_POST` или `$_GET` соответственно.

У Вас же их нет, поэтому такая ошибка.

Решение:

```
echo 'Bird: <select name="bird">';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">';
    echo $row['name'];
    echo '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

echo '<br>Place: <input type="text" name="place">';
echo '<br>Time: <input  type="text" name="time">';
echo '<br>Email: <input type="text" name="email">';
echo '<br>Place: <input type="submit" value="Save">';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Сделал всё в точности как у вас, но таблица не заполняется.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает!